# Правильное чтение картинки

Tags: xna, c#

Всем привет, скажите вот я хочу использовать спрайт

[image]

Скажите как сделать чтобы при событии:

```
        if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            position.Y += 10;
        if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            position.X -= 10;
        if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            position.X += 10;
        if (keystate.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            position.Y -= 10;
```

Не вся эта картинка двигалась на только 2 строчка, и по очереди?

Comment: Передавайте `sourceRectangle` с координатами необходимой части спрайта в метод `SpriteBatch.Draw()`; [подробнее](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189833/what-is-source-rectangle-in-spritebatch-draw-in-xna).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно пересоздавать картинку. Класс `Bitmap` имеет методы `GetPixel` и `SetPixel` для задания цвета пикселя. Они обеспечивают доступ к цветам в указанных пикселях.

Comment: Нет вы верно не поняли, я хочу картинку превратить в анимацию, но не просто в анимацию, а чтобы только при нажатии на кнопку просто "сектор" откуда читается картинка ++ и бралась уже соседняя картинка, и так если быстро вот и анимация, я вот это хочу сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший туториал по XNA: [RB Whitaker's Wiki](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials)

Конкретно ваш случай: [2D Tutorials -> Texture Atlases](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/texture-atlases-1)

Фон лучше сделать прозрачным, или обработать в шейдере. Шейдеры тоже есть в туториале.

Comment: Постарайтесь добавлять ключевые моменты прямо в ответ, потому что ссылки имеют свойство умирать.

Comment: Первая ссылка не содержит ссылки.